# Remove rewind from Owl Carousel v2

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I'm using the Owl Carousel on my website and it works pretty smoothly overall, but when reaching the end of the images, the carousel rewinds to the beginning. I would like to have a continuous loop, with no rewind animation inbetween. I've tried using "rewind:false," and another StackOverflow post suggested using "rewindNav:false," but neither of them work. Is this a bug or am I using the wrong options?

```
<script>
          $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            nav:true,
            rewindNav:false,
            rewind:false,
            autoplay:true,
            autoplayTimeout:4000,
            autoplayHoverPause:true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },
                600:{
                    items:1
                },
                1000:{
                    items:1
                }
    }

          });

        </script>
```

Comment: I've managed to solve this. Apparently you need to incorporate 'checkVisibility:true' in the code. This will fix the broken rewind as well as some other issues.